# NSString out of scope in init method

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have class, that has a NSString.

```
@interface AudioManager : NSObject {
    AudioData *data_;
    NSString *requiredMusic_;
    NSTimer *timer_;
    MUSIC_ID musicId_;
    float fadeIncrement_;
}
```

When i'm looking at `requiredMusic_` variable via debugger in `init` method it's written that `NSCFString ... out of scope`. But if i will look at this variable from `self` then it will be written it's nil!

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        data_ = &[[GameDataObject sharedObject] data]->audioData();
        requiredMusic_ = @"bla bla bla";
        musicId_ = MUSIC_OTHER;
    }
    return self;
}
```

`Out of scope` is also written in other places and my code is not working as expected. What is the problem ?

```
-(void) changeBackgroundMusic:(NSString *)path
{
    [requiredMusic_ release];
    requiredMusic_ = path;
    [requiredMusic_ retain];
...
}
```

In the code above it's also out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably debugging a version of your program compiled with optimisation enabled. In optimized code, some variable may not be accessible via the debugger, because when compiling the compiler found that in this current function the variable scope can be reduced without changing the semantic and it did just that to improve the code (reduce register usage or memory access, ...).

You can try to recompile it with optimisation disabled. Depending on the compiler, it is possible to disable optimisation for just a part of a file with some `#pragma` (for GCC this was introduced in version 4.4).

Comment: how can i disable optimization ?

Answer (score 0):

What Sylvain said.  But...

```
    data_ = &[[GameDataObject sharedObject] data]->audioData();
```

Don't do that!   You will be taking the address of a return value which is pretty much guaranteed to not at all be what you want and I'm surprised the compiler even compiles that.

Comment: Everything is ok here. AudioData() is returning reference. So i'm taking an adress of a real variable. Not a copy.  const AudioData & audioData() const {return audio_;}

Comment: It is still a distinctly odd design.  Fragile, too.   You are effectively ripping away a few layers of encapsulation.  If you really want to have the address of a variable you should have API to return that address directly and no rely on grabbing it in the caller.  Much less fragile that way (without seeing considerably more code, hard to say more).

Comment: This is the only part of the code i'm doing so. Just to keep a pointer to the variable to have direct access. In c++ i would make a const reference to this variable and initialize it in constructor. But i can't do this in objective-c.